# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'c'

Tags: python

i tried to make a project number guessing.
and i received an error:ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'c'

```
import random

print('i am think about a number between 1-20......\nwhould you try to discover?')
computer = random.randint(1,20)
for i in range(1,4):

    user = int(input("for a clue enter the letter 'c'\n enter a number between 1-20: "))
    if user == 'c':
        if int(computer) %2 == 0:
            print('this number is even number')
        else:
            print('this number is odd number')
    if user > computer :
        print('your choice is bigger than i thought\ntry again')
    elif user < computer:
        print('your choice is smaller than i thought\ntry again.')
    else:
        break
    
if user == computer:
    print('correct!!! you did it!!!')
else:
    print("better luck  next time the number i thought about is: " + str(computer))
```

Comment: Convert the input to `int()` *after* you have checked whether it `== 'c'` or not…

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert `user` variable to `int` after check `if user == 'c`:`.

```py
import random

print('i am think about a number between 1-20......\nwhould you try to discover?')
computer = random.randint(1,20)
for i in range(1,4):

    user = input("for a clue enter the letter 'c'\n enter a number between 1-20: ")
    if user == 'c':
        if int(computer) %2 == 0:
            print('this number is even number')
        else:
            print('this number is odd number')
    else:
        user = int(user)
        if user > computer :
            print('your choice is bigger than i thought\ntry again')
        elif user < computer:
            print('your choice is smaller than i thought\ntry again.')
        else:
            break
    
if user == computer:
    print('correct!!! you did it!!!')
else:
    print("better luck  next time the number i thought about is: " + str(computer))
```